# Unit Test Case For TempData[] Initialization ASP>NET Core Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

```
 public ActionResult ChoiceView(string name)
    {
        if (TempData["SessionVariable"] != null)
        {

            FileName = name;

            return View();
        }
        else
        {

            return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
        }

    }
```

In code I had initialize Tempdata in previous controller.

while writing TestCase How to initialize and use TempData ?

Comment: you need a stubbing/mocking framework. There are plenty available. One such framework is:  NStubstitute: http://nsubstitute.github.io/ use it to initialize and stub out TempData

Comment: Any Examples For this testcase using NStustitute ? @BKSpurgeon

Comment: more info on what temp data is? I'm not at all familiar with ASP.net check google to see if you can mock/stub it